# Why am i getting this Unbound Local Error using a package which is wrapper around gridsearchCV? (hyperclassifersearch)

Tags: python, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am using the hyperclassifiersearch package to run my gridsearch with pipeline. One thing i do not understand is that when i use One Hot encoding ( when i switch to targetencoding i don't get the error) i get this error from running the below:

```
     86 
     87         print('Search is done.')
---> 88         return best_model # allows to predict with the best model overall
     89 
     90     def evaluate_model(self, sort_by='mean_test_score', show_timing_info=False):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'best_model' referenced before assignment
```

The code i used to generate that error is as follows:

```
#define pipeline

    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='constant', fill_value=0))]
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_cols)])
    model = XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic',n_jobs=-1_label_encoder=False)
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('clf', model)])


models = { 
                
    'xgb' : pipeline } 

params = { 
    'xgb': { 'clf__n_estimators': [200,300]}
        }
    

    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42,shuffle=True)


    search = HyperclassifierSearch(models, params)
    gridsearch = search.train_model(X_train, y_train, cv=cv,scoring='recall')
```

I dont understand this error? Can anybody help https://github.com/janhenner/HyperclassifierSearch <-- repo to package.

Comment: error means you try to use variable `best_model` before it is created. So first you have to create it - ie. `best_model = ... some value ...` - and later you can use it `return best_model`. Probably you have `best_model = ...` in some `if` and it is never excuted so it never create this variable. You should have `best_model = None` at the beginning to assing some default value.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

[Full code](https://github.com/janhenner/HyperclassifierSearch/blob/main/HyperclassifierSearch/HyperclassifierSearch.py#L50) is

```
def train_model(self, X_train, y_train, search='grid', **search_kwargs):
        """
        Optimizing over one or multiple classifiers or pipelines.
        Input:
        X : array or dataframe with features; this should be a training dataset
        y : array or dataframe with label(s); this should be a training dataset
        Output:
        returns the optimal model according to the scoring metric
        Parameters:
        search : str, default='grid'
            define the search
            ``grid`` performs GridSearchCV
            ``random`` performs RandomizedSearchCV
        **search_kwargs : kwargs
            additional parameters passed to the search
        """
        grid_results = {}
        best_score = 0

        for key in self.models.keys():
            print('Search for {}'.format(key), '...')
            assert search in ('grid', 'random'), 'search parameter out of range'
            if search=='grid':
                grid = GridSearchCV(self.models[key], self.params[key], **search_kwargs)
            if search=='random':
                grid = RandomizedSearchCV(self.models[key], self.params[key], **search_kwargs)
            grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
            self.grid_results[key] = grid

            if grid.best_score_ > best_score: # return best model
                best_score = grid.best_score_
                best_model = grid

        print('Search is done.')
        return best_model # allows to predict with the best model overall
```

but it seems in some situations all models may have `score <= 0` and then it doesn't run

```
best_model = grid
```

so variable `best_model` is not created and it can't run `return best_model`.

You should assign default value - i.e. `best_model = None` - to have this value at start.

Or you should use lower score at start - i.e. `best_score = -1`

---

This problem you should send to author of this module.

---

**EDIT:**

I added `best_model = None` but now you have to remember to check if you not get `None` when you run it.

```
    """
    Optimizing over one or multiple classifiers or pipelines.
    Input:
    X : array or dataframe with features; this should be a training dataset
    y : array or dataframe with label(s); this should be a training dataset
    Output:
    returns the optimal model according to the scoring metric
    Parameters:
    search : str, default='grid'
        define the search
        ``grid`` performs GridSearchCV
        ``random`` performs RandomizedSearchCV
    **search_kwargs : kwargs
        additional parameters passed to the search
    """
    grid_results = {}
    best_score = 0

    best_model = None   # <--- default value at start

    for key in self.models.keys():
        print('Search for {}'.format(key), '...')
        assert search in ('grid', 'random'), 'search parameter out of range'
        if search=='grid':
            grid = GridSearchCV(self.models[key], self.params[key], **search_kwargs)
        if search=='random':
            grid = RandomizedSearchCV(self.models[key], self.params[key], **search_kwargs)
        grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
        self.grid_results[key] = grid

        if grid.best_score_ > best_score: # return best model
            best_score = grid.best_score_
            best_model = grid

    print('Search is done.')
    return best_model # allows to predict with the best model overall
```

And later

```
gridsearch = search.train_model(X_train, y_train, cv=cv,scoring='recall')

if not gridsearch:  # check if None
   print("Didn't find model")
else:
   # ... code ...
```